# How to create Table in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

**Create Table in Crystal Report**

I am newbie to Crystal Report, and i am using Crystal Report 2008.  I want to know, do we have table object in Crystal Report.. so that i can draw a table with specific rows and columns, and drag and drop the items to each and every table cell as per the requirement.

The problem i am facing without using table object is that, i have to align each and every element either it is text field or database field from the field explorer, so that it looks like a table and it is too much time taking.

If it can be done in Higher versions of Crystal Reports, then please give details.

Answer (score 2):

you have to draw tables mannually in CR, using the line and box items from the designer,

alignment is also available, you can use gridlines and alignment options of crystal reports, its not hard at all..

Comment: Can't it be possible in higher versions of CR Tool

Comment: these are the tools available in CR, its pretty easy to make tables this way, insert box and then lines and you should get a neat table

Comment: I disagree that it's easy. Compared to SSRS it is a major pain. (Not to say there aren't features in Crystal that are better, i.e. designing in preview mode.). There should be a table object that you can drag fields into and it will auto create the headers to the same as the field name. Drawing a table every time you want data detail is a complete waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Insert - Ole Object - Microsoft Office Excel
It will add a excel file in your report. By dragging vertical reduce the excel object to one row and and horizontally to your required no. of Columns.

That will create a table with one row and many columns and can grow automatically in Detail section.